# HeapSort implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have implemented the heap sort algorithm which passes my tests. Although, I would like to ask you if I can improve anything from readability to performance.

```
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Orestis on 17/07/2015
 */

public class HeapSort {

    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
        heapSort(list);
    }


    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void heapSort(List<T> list){
        int heapSize = list.size() - 1;
        buildMaxHeap(list, heapSize);
        for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            exchange(0, i, list);
            heapSize--;
            maxHeapify(list, 0, heapSize);
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * Maintain the max-heap property (list[find_parent(i)] >= list[i])
     * If the max-heap property is violated float down list[i]
     */
    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void maxHeapify(List<T> list, int index, int heapSize) {
        int largest = index; // initialise largest to index.

        int left = findLeftIndex(index);
        int right = findRightIndex(index);

        if (left <= heapSize && list.get(left).compareTo(list.get(index)) >= 1) {
            largest = left;
        }

        if (right <= heapSize && list.get(right).compareTo(list.get(largest)) >= 1) {
            largest = right;
        }

        if (largest != index) {
            exchange(index, largest, list);
            maxHeapify(list, largest, heapSize);
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * This function goes through the remaining nodes of the heap tree and
     * runs maxHeapify on each one.
     */
    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void buildMaxHeap(List<T> list, int heapSize) {
        int start = (int) Math.floor((heapSize / 2));
        for (int i = start; i >= 0; i--) {
            maxHeapify(list, i, heapSize);
        }
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void exchange(int i, int largest, List<T> array){
        T temp = array.get(largest);
        array.set(largest, array.get(i));
        array.set(i, temp);
    }

    private static int findParentIndex(int index) {
        return (index >> 1) ^ 1;
    }

    private static int findLeftIndex(int index) {
        return (index << 1) ^ 1;
    }

    private static int findRightIndex(int index) {
        return (index << 1) + 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What comes to performance, it will degrade drastically if you pass a `LinkedList` (which implements `java.util.List` interface accepted in your heap sort): for such a list, `get(int)` operation runs not in constant time, but rather \$O(n)\$. In order to deal with it, check in your sort that the input list is not a linked list, and if it is, copy all the elements to an `ArrayList`, sort it, and load back to the input list.

The second point concerns the sifting algorithm. If the indices of the sifting operations are \$i_1, i_2, ..., i_n\$, you first swap \$i_1\$ with \$i_2\$, then \$i_2\$ with \$i_3\$ and so on until the element is in its proper place \$i_n\$. You can do better: save the element at \$i_1\$, then move \$i_2\$ to \$i_1\$, \$i_3\$ to \$i_2\$, and so on. Finally, just set the saved element at index \$i_n\$. This optimization does not improve the time complexity of heap sort, yet it reduces the constant factors hidden by the big-O notation.

The last, but not least: sometimes we do not need to sort the entire array/list. For this, it makes sense to code up a sorting routine, which can sort particular ranges. Then, in order to sort the entire array/list - as you do - you can just do:

```
sort(List<T> list) {
    sort(list, 0, list.size());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Instead of:

  ```
  heapSize--;
  maxHeapify(list, 0, heapSize);
  ```

  you could shorter write:

  ```
  maxHeapify(list, 0, --heapSize);
  ```
- Instead of:

  ```
  int start = (int) Math.floor((heapSize / 2));
  ```

  you could use [`Math.floorDiv()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorDiv-int-int-) which is shorter and most probably more performant, as well:

  ```
  int start = Math.floorDiv(heapSize, 2);
  ```